# VB.Net - Importa Null para System.Byte

Tags: vb.net

Não estou conseguindo retornar o valor NULL do SQL Server que está em uma coluna do tipo byte.

Mensagem:

> {"Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.DBNull' no tipo 'System.Byte[]'."}

Código:

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(ObtemImagem(CInt(dgvAgenda.SelectedCells(0).Value)))
            picImagem.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Erro: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Função Obter Imagem
    Function ObtemImagem(ByVal Img As Integer) As Byte()

        Dim Imagem() As Byte = Nothing

        With sqlCmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = "SELECT Imagem FROM CadastroInfantil WHERE IdAAInfantil = " & Img
            .Connection = sqlCon
        End With
        Try
            sqlCon.Open()

         Imagem = CType(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Erro: " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            sqlCon.Close()
        End Try
        Return Imagem
    End Function
```

Se poderem me ajudar agradeço...

Comment: `CType()` é pra converter o resultado do SQL em Byte, certo?

Comment: Precisa retornar o resultado mesmo quando nulo?

Comment: Desculpe Math estou aperndendo ainda e peguei esse exemplo do site Macoratti, eu fiz a importação dos dados que estava em exel para o banco e as colunas que estavam vazias ficaram com o valor null e na hora de trazer a informação que no caso e mostrar uma foto da esse erro.

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer isso, pode ser que não funcione, mas vale a pena tentar.

```
 Dim ms As New MemoryStream(ObtemImagem(CInt(dgvAgenda.SelectedCells(0).Value)))
        picImagem.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Erro: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

'Função Obter Imagem
Function ObtemImagem(ByVal Img As Integer) As Byte()

    Dim Imagem() As Byte = Nothing

    With sqlCmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = "SELECT Imagem FROM CadastroInfantil WHERE IdAAInfantil = " & Img
        .Connection = sqlCon
    End With
    Try
        sqlCon.Open()

        Dim tmp = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()

        If Not TypeOf tmp Is System.DBNull
             If Byte.TryParse(tmp) = True
                   Imagem = CType(tmp, Byte())
             End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Erro: " + ex.Message)
    Finally
        sqlCon.Close()
    End Try
    Return Imagem
End Function
```

Comment: Obrigado CypherPotato problema resolvido...

Comment: Considere clicar no símbolo de correto e clicar na setinha para cima ao lado da resposta, irá me ajudar muito!